# pyplot bar chart with categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
    x   y   cat
0   1   2   1
1   2   3   1
2   3   4   1
3   1   2   2
4   2   3   2
5   3   8   2
```

So I have some x-y-values together with a category.

Now I want to make a bar chart with with per x-value (1,2 and 3) two bars showing the y-values of the two categories. This shouldnt be so complicated but for some reason, this still works:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(df[df["cat"] == 1]["x"]-0.2, df[df["cat"] == 1]["y"],width=0.2,color='b',align='center')
plt.show()
```

But when I add the second category:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(df[df["cat"] == 1]["x"]-0.2, df[df["cat"] == 1]["y"],width=0.2,color='b',align='center')
ax.bar(df[df["cat"] == 2]["x"]+0.2, df[df["cat"] == 2]["y"],width=0.2,color='g',align='center')
plt.show()
```

python starts complaining about a key error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-2188371c6b12> in <module>()
      1 ax = plt.subplot(111)
      2 ax.bar(df[df["cat"] == 1]["x"]-0.2, df[df["cat"] == 1]["y"],width=0.2,color='b',align='center')
----> 3 ax.bar(df[df["cat"] == 2]["x"]+0.2, df[df["cat"] == 1]["y"],width=0.2,color='b',align='center')
      4 plt.show()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1890                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1891                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1892             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1893         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1894         if pre_doc is None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in bar(self, left, height, width, bottom, **kwargs)
   2103         if align == 'center':
   2104             if orientation == 'vertical':
-> 2105                 left = [left[i] - width[i] / 2. for i in xrange(len(left))]
   2106             elif orientation == 'horizontal':
   2107                 bottom = [bottom[i] - height[i] / 2.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   2103         if align == 'center':
   2104             if orientation == 'vertical':
-> 2105                 left = [left[i] - width[i] / 2. for i in xrange(len(left))]
   2106             elif orientation == 'horizontal':
   2107                 bottom = [bottom[i] - height[i] / 2.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    601         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    602         try:
--> 603             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    604 
    605             if not is_scalar(result):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2167         try:
   2168             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2169                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2170         except KeyError as e1:
   2171             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3557)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3240)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8564)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8508)()

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it.

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar( (df[df["cat"] == 1]["x"]-0.2).tolist(), df[df["cat"] == 1]["y"].tolist(),width=0.2,color='b',align='center')
ax.bar( (df[df["cat"] == 2]["x"]+0.2).tolist(), df[df["cat"] == 2]["y"].tolist(),width=0.2,color='g',align='center')
plt.show()
```

The problem is that `df[df["cat"] == 1]["x"]` doesnt return a list but a Series, so including the index. And apparantly this index is actually used by pyplot is in some way it actually shouldn't.. because if we make a list out of it explicitly, it all works:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This also works as a one line solutions in pandas:

```
df.pivot_table(values='y', index='x', columns='cat').plot.bar()
```

The `pivot_table` call will create a table that looks like:

```
cat  1  2
x        
1    2  2
2    3  3
3    4  8
```